# Código fonte é exibido na tela e não é executado

Tags: php

Um código meu deu problema e ficou aparecendo alguns trechos dele em uma tela em branco quando eu executava:

[image: Demonstração]

O código estava certo, não sabia qual era o problema, então fui testar um outro código que uns dias atras tinha funcionado perfeitamente (eu não modifiquei ele de forma alguma, nem mesmo abri o código) e também não funcionou, aconteceu o mesmo problema dos trechos na tela:

```
"; } ?>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Poste o código com problema.

Comment: O primeiro codigo "http://www.mediafire.com/download/rpczqpm3luxykmk/SistemaDeLogin.rar" e o segundo "http://www.mediafire.com/download/f92glgasmxuc8dc/TesteUpload.rar".

Comment: Coloque o código que está com problema na pergunta.

Comment: Que servidor HTTP está usando? Como instalou o PHP? Testou sem nenhum .htaccess na pasta? Se a instalação do PHP está correta, o problema é fechamento de tags. Poste o código na questão.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isso acontece quando a [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)(`<?`) não está habilitada no servidor, para solucionar o problema troque todas as ocorrências de:

```
<?
```

para

```
<?php
```

Outra forma é habilita-la pelo php.ini, após a alteração reinicie o servidor.

Mude o valor:

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

Para:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Outra causa pode ser o acesso errado ao arquivo(via navegador), não funciona chamar a url `fil:///c:\projeto\arquivo.php` o correto é algo como `http://localhost/projeto/arquivo.php`

Comment: Eu tinha me esqueci que reinstalei o WAMP e esqueci de habilitar, vlw pela força mano

Comment: Não resolveu no meu, o inicío da tag já está <?php e o término ?>

Comment: @CaioVieira vc mudou a forma de acessar a url?

Comment: mudei e não acessou o arquivo, eu deixei assim: http://localhost/wamp/www/meixautonomoresultados.php

Comment: com http antes de localhost

Comment: @CaioVieira http://localhost/meixautonomoresultados.php  assim vc consegue acessar?

Comment: não consegui...

Comment: @CaioVieira o wamp está ligado? qual o nome da pasta do seu projeto? se tentar só http://localhost o que acontece?