# Short Tags php em servidor

Tags: php

Olá, hospedo no meu PC e funciona corretamente, porem quando coloquei em um VPS aconteceu esses "bugs", eu já ativei as short tags e as asp tags, oque sera que pode ser ??

Pode ser visto acessando o [site](http://www.luppbox.com/) ou por essa imagem

[image]

Comment: [Código fonte é exibido na tela e não é executado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60365/91)

Comment: Mas elas estão ativadas

Comment: Ela aparece ativa no `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Realmente, esta OFF, porem no arquivo ela esta ON, tem alguma maneira de fazer isso direto pelo CMD do ubuntu ??

Comment: Olá, já corrigi o problema, obrigado

Comment: Veja esse [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/367090) mostra como editar o arquivo pelo terminal, lembre de reiniciar o apache depois da mudança.