# Problema com Echo php

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer uma busca num sistema aqui de um trabalho da faculdade, mas quando exibe o resultado aparece:

```
0) { echo "$count resultados encontrados!"; } while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { echo "$dados[nome] $dados[email]"; } ?>
```

o codigo ta assim:

```
include "config.php";

$busca = $_POST['busca'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *
    FROM funcionario
    WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' OR email LIKE '%$busca%' ");

    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    $noticia = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

if ($count == 0) {
    echo "Nenhum resultado!";
}

if ($count > 0) {
        echo "$count resultados encontrados!";
    }

while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "$dados[nome] $dados[email]";
}
```

Poderiam me ajudar a encontrar o erro por favor?

Comment: Fernando, poderia explicar melhor o erro que aparece, está aparecendo aquele código php `0) { echo "$count resultados encontrados!"; }...`?

Comment: tipo, na pagina que seria exibido o resultado, ao inves de imprimir na pagina que tem algum resultado, aparece escrito esses comandos 0) { echo "$count resultados encontrados!"; }...  Praticamente esta como se tivesse: echo "0) { echo "$count resultados encontrados!"; }..."

Comment: o código fonte é impresso na tela no lugar do verdadeiro resultado?

Comment: sim rray, mas não o codigo fonte inteiro, só esse trecho que citei.

Comment: É estranho isso. Se imprimisse o código todo eu diria que o PHP não está sendo interpretado (pela falta de um `<?php`, talvez), mas essa de imprimir só um fragmento... bizarro.

Comment: Veja se algum [desses procedimentos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60365/91) resolve. Como vc está acessando seu php na barra de endereeços do navegador.

Comment: Fernando, o código inserido na pergunta é todo o código do arquivo? Se não, tem como postar o código completo?

Comment: acessando como localhost/busca_func.php, irei conferir aqui rray.
Kadu esse é todo o arquivo de busca., so não coloquei o <? ?> aqui no stack.

Comment: `<?` não funciona corretamente se a short_open_tag não estiver habilitada, outra causa disso é quando vc acessa a url como `file:///algum_arquivo.php`.

Comment: Fernando, troca o `<?` por `<?php` como na resposta que o @rray citou.

Comment: Pronto, gente realmente funcionou, muito obrigado a todos voces. Não acredito que estou a 4 horas pelejando com esse erro '-'.

Comment: Argh, entendi. O browser interpretou `<? ... if ($count >` como uma grande tag HTML, e o que vem depois, como conteúdo.

Answer (score 0):

As short tags devem estar habilitadas para `< ?` funcionar:

**php.ini**

`short_open_tag=On`

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag