# Diferença entre tags do php <?php e <?=

Tags: php

Bem estou aprendendo `Laravel` e fiquei com uma dúvida seguindo alguns tutoriais.

Em certo momentos dentro da `view`  é utilizado a tag : `<?php foreach($produtos as $p): ?>`
e quando vou pegar os dados `<?= $p->nome ?>`.

Existe algum diferença entre `<?php` e `<?=`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sim, existe.

A tag `<?php` é a padrão para aberturas de arquivo PHP, a menos que esteja habilitado o [Short Tag](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), que permite abrir o PHP com `<?` (o que pode conflitar com instruções XML)

Já a tag `<?=` é bem simples o intuito dela:

> Nota: Esta diretiva também afeta a forma abreviada `<?=` anteriores ao `PHP > 5.4.0`, que é a mesma que `<? echo`. Para uso desta abreviatura é 
>   necessário que short_open_tag esteja ativo. Desde `PHP 5.4.0`, `<?=` está sempre disponível.

Ao invés de usar `<?php echo $variable; ?>` basta usar `<?=$variable?>`

Afins do código ficar mais clean e legível.

Devo ressaltar que isso não é do Laravel como descrito na pergunta, e sim do PHP.

## Considerações

Como esteja estudando Laravel e se barrou nessa questão de repassar valores para `views` recomendo aproveitar e estudar o [Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)

No blade dar output de variaveis apenas usando:

```
{{ $variable }}
```

Que é equivalente a:

```
echo $variable;
```

Muito mais simples, né?

Comment: +1 por citar o blade.

Comment: Blade é um dos próximos tópicos do livro que estou seguindo. Vlw pela dica.

Comment: O `twig` também é top. Porém ele transforma o PHP praticamente em outra linguagem (a grosso modo)

Comment: @juniorb2ss complementei sua resposta com um pequeno detalhe, para facilitar a concentração de outras perguntas duplicadas pelo site.

Answer (score 15):

Sim, `<?php` é a opção mais correta para abrir a tag do php, pois nem sempre o servidor está com `open_short_tag` habilitada, geralmente o que acontece é o [código php ser impresso na tela e não executado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60365/91).

A partir da versão 5.4 `<?=` voltou a ser padrão.

Devo ou não usar `<?=` ? a melhor resposta é esse fluxograma retirado do [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/151694/106391)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 8):

A sintaxe `<?= ?>` é um atalho para isto:

```
<?php echo        ; ?>
```

Antes do PHP 5.4 a opção [short tags](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) deveria estar habilitada para poder se usar este atalho. No PHP 5.4 essa opção passou a estar sempre disponível.

Tanto é que essa sintaxe é especificada na **[documentação do echo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.echo.php)**.

Exemplo:

```
<p>Meu nome é <?=$nome?></p>
```

equivale a

```
<p>Meu nome é <?php echo $nome; ?></p>
```

Antes desta mudança do PHP 5.4, o uso do `echo` implícito era problemático, pois as tags curtas de abertura `<? ?>`se confundiam com instruções XML, e normalmente as hospedagens em geral mantém essa opção desligada.

Como o sinal de `=` serviria em teoria para desambiguação nestes casos, resolveu-se habilitar esta opção separadamente da configuração das tags curtas.

Answer (score 7):

Sim, quando você usa `<?=...` é como se estivesse fazendo`<?php echo...` é só uma forma abreviada para manter o código mais limpo.

Answer (score 4):

Há também o asp_tags `<%%>`, que foi criado para facilitar que programadores ASP migrassem para o PHP, há 15 anos atrás.

Havia também outros propósitos como o intuito de poder criar sistema de templates compatíveis com ASP e PHP.

Na prática mesmo, isso nunca ocorreu. Pelo menos não conforme esperava-se.

Há outra tag que particularmente nunca vi usarem `<script language="php">`.

No PHP 7.0.0, as tags ASP e script foram removidas.

Answer (score 3):

Só para complementar com uma informação, uma das formas citadas é chamada pelo PHP de `alternative syntax`, ou sintaxe alternativa.

Ela serve para poder simplificar a forma de escrever uma estrutura de controle ou de repetição, em caso de ter que "misturar" o PHP com HTML.

Exemplo:

```
<?php foreach($produtos as $p): ?>
   <p> <?= $p->nome ?></p>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Outro exemplo de sintaxe alternativa (sem misturar com HTML):

```
if ($produtos->isEmpty()) :
    echo "Nenhum produto encontrado";
endif
```