# Utilização de TAGS no PHP

Tags: php, html-tags

Uso da TAG `<?=`

No site do PHP, diz que [não é recomendado](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) utilizar essa sintaxe de tag. Segue abaixo o trecho.

> Quando o PHP interpreta um arquivo ele procura pelas tags de abertura
>   e fechamento, , que dizem ao PHP para iniciar ou parar a
>   interpretação do código entre elas. A interpretação dessa maneira,
>   permite o PHP ser incluído em vários tipos de documentos, pois tudo
>   que está fora dessas tags é ignorado pelo interpretador do PHP.
>
> O PHP também permite a tag curta

Porém, a partir do PHP5.4 essa opção vem por padrão habilitado no PHP, e continua o mesmo até hoje(versão PHP7).

A real pergunta é, **continua sendo não recomendado utilizar a tag `<?=`** ? Se sim, qual o seu real problema ?

Se não, será que o artigo do site do [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) não esta desatualizado ?

Tem essa [pergunta do StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) que aborda essa duvida, porém, é de 7 anos atrás que provavelmente é do tempo do PHP5.3.4(Nessa versão, tinha que habilitar a opção de tag no php.ini).

Comment: [Diferença entre tags do php <?php e <?=](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89835/91)

Comment: Obrigado @rray, não tinha encontrado essa pergunta. Vou exclui a que criei.

Comment: @LucaoA nao precisa excluir, ela pode servir como referencia pra outra, ajudando nas pesquisas. Fechei como duplicata pois quem achar a sua vai ter o link pra outra. A duplicata é uma forma de aumentar a chance das pessoas encontrarem o que querem, pesquisando por termos diferentes, e ao mesmo tempo ter todas as respostas centralizadas.

Comment: @Bacco Entendi. Sem problemas, não vou excluí esse post.