# Concatenar Javascript com PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Eu estou tentando concatenar PHP com Javascript, mas não estou conseguindo.

```html
<button onclick="gravaDados('/" . <?php echo nomeCliente; ?> . /"')" class="btn-playpause">Play</button>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Aqui vamos nós:

```
<button onclick="gravaDados('<?= $nomeCliente; ?>')" class="btn-playpause">Play</button>
```

As tags `<?= ?>` querem dizer a mesma coisa que `<?php echo ...; ?>`.

[Diferença entre tags do php <?php e <?=](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89835/5878)

Pensando melhor, você não precisa de contra-barras. Use apenas as aspas simples, que você vai ter o resultado que busca.

Caso o seu Apache ou IIS, enfim, CGI, não tenha habilitada a permissão ou o uso das tags curtas do PHP, você pode usar:

```
<button onclick="gravaDados('<?php echo $nomeCliente; ?>')" class="btn-playpause">Play</button>
```

Não se esqueça de usar `$` antes do nome da variável para indicar variáveis no PHP.

Comment: Você manda, @AndersonCarlosWoss!

Comment: Desculpa, mas minha resposta foi dada. Eu não preciso de um ensaio acadêmico para responder uma pergunta tão simples. As configurações default do PHP sim, permitem que a partir da versão 5.4 as tags nessa forma sejam usadas, mas por conta de problemas com XML, alguns servidores desabilitam no Apache o seu uso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Toda a razão mas nem todo o servidor tem a versão mais atualizada do php ainda existem hospedagem com php 5.3 o que é 3 vezes mais lento que php 7

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra alternativa talvez seja utilizar o `printf` (ou `sprintf` dependendo do caso):

```
printf('<button onclick="gravaDados(\'%s\')" class="btn-playpause">Play</button>', $nomeCliente);
```

Não acredito que seja a melhor opção, mas é um outra opção.

---

Dependendo do contexto acredito que convém codificar o HTML do `$nomeCliente` afim mitigar XSS, neste caso algo como:

```
printf('<button onclick="gravaDados(\'%s\')" class="btn-playpause">Play</button>',
htmlentities($nomeCliente, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8'));
```

Sem utilizar o `htmlentities`, do jeito que as outras respostas fizeram, se o valor do `$nomeCliente` for `);alert('XSS` irá injetar um alerta (ou qualquer outro código malicioso que o usuário quiser, óbviamente) no website, [veja aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f32ee67e0424b6968d43464d1216cfed8207b4a9).

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que não precisas de escapar as aspas ate porque para espaca-las é com `\`  e ao mesmo tempos estas a fazer concatenação fora do **PHP**

Basta assim:

```
<button onclick="return gravaDados('<?php echo $nomeCliente; ?>');" class="btn-playpause">Play</button>
```