# Carregar foto padrão se não houver foto cadastrada

Tags: php

Olá, como eu faço para carregar uma foto padrão para visualização caso eu não tenha cadastrado uma foto do cliente?

Eu trago a imagem para a visualização assim:

```html
<img src="fotos/<?php echo $dados["foto"]; ?>" width='120' />
```

Então caso eu não cadastre nenhuma foto para o cliente, ele carregue uma foto padrão.

Comment: Você pode usar: `if..else`, ternário ou *null coalesce operator*

Comment: Sim, mas como? Tentei algumas coisas e não consegui, por isso perguntei aqui para algum exemplo no que coloquei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, como mencionado nos comentários, você pode fazer isso facilmente utilizando `if` e `else`, segue um exemplo:

```
<?php 

if (!empty($dados['foto'])) { 
    echo "<img src='".$dados['foto']."'/>";
}

else {
    echo "<img src='linkdaimagempadrao.png'/>";
}

?>
```

Se existir dados no elemento `foto`, irá ser exibido, se não, será exibida a imagem do `else`.
Lembrando que precisaria estar dentro de um `while` e passando os parâmetros corretos.

> Sempre coloque o código completo, para facilitar as pessoas que vão te ajudar, e ajuda a você mesmo a rever o seu código.

Answer (score 3):

Se estiver utilizando o PHP 7, você pode utilizar o [operador de coalescência nula](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) para verificar se há algum valor na sua variável e, se não houver, exibir um valor padrão.

```php
<img src="fotos/<?= $dados["foto"] ?? "default.png" ?>" width='120' />
```

Aproveitei também para substituir a estrutura `<?php echo` por `<?=`, que são equivalentes.

Veja mais em [Diferença entre tags do php <?php e <?=](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89835/5878)

> **Nota:** Será exibida a imagem `default.png` apenas se `$dados["foto"]` for nulo ou não estiver definido. Valores como `""`, `false`, etc seriam considerados válidos. Você pode utilizar o operador `?:` ou ainda fazer todas as condições necessárias manualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Faça um  `IF...Else` verificando se o valor passado  `$dados["foto"]` for nulo, você atribui ao  `$dados["foto"]` uma imagem padrão:

`$dados["foto"] = "caminhodasuaimagem.extensão"`

Answer (score -1):

Samuel, resolveu sim, ontem eu tinha achado uma solução, e funciona aqui no php 7.3, mas achei seu código mais limpo. O que eu tinha colocado era esse abaixo.

```html
<?php if($foto){ ?>

<img src="fotos/<?php echo $dados["foto"]; ?>" width='120' />

  <?php }else{ ?>
  
<img src="fotos/sem_foto.jpg" width='120'>

<?php } ?>
```

Hoje peguei o seu e adaptei.

```html
<?php 

if (!empty($dados['foto'])) { 
    echo "<img src='fotos/".$dados['foto']."' width='120'/>";
}

else{
    echo "<img src='fotos/sem_foto.jpg' width='120'/>";
}

?>
```

Não sei se os dois estão ok, funcionam, porém não sei qual é o melhor, apesar de achar o seu mais limpo