# Dúvida de código

Tags: php

Alguém poderia me explicar pq o loop não está funcionando, antigamente funcionava e a agr to quebrando a cabeça sem entender nada, parece não está sendo interpretado sei lá. O "hello world" acima funciona, mas quando é pra interagir com HTML o PHP não funciona.

```
<?='hello world'?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Portal Noticias</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="titulo">
            Portal Noticias
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="noticias">
        <?for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { ?>
            <article class="artigo">
                <h1>Titulo da noticia</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, bla bla bla, consecetur. Lorem ipsum bla bla.
                </p>
            </article>
        <?}?> 

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tente utilizar `<?php` em vez de `<?`.

Answer (score 3):

> Modifiquei seu código em PHP, para que seja possível visualizar a resposta com mais facilidade. Mas nada impede que você utilize do seu jeito. Porém para simplificar a explicação, coloquei da forma a seguir.

A tag `<?php` é a padrão para aberturas de arquivo PHP, a menos que esteja habilitado o Short Tag, que permite abrir o PHP com `<?`.
Já a tag `<?=` é bem simples o intuito dela, ao invés de usar `<?php echo $variable; ?>` basta usar `<?=$variable?>`. Afim do código ficar mais clean e legível. Referência: [SOpt - juniorb2ss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89835/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-tags-do-php-php-e)

Você pode visualizar um pouco mais sobre a linguagem em: [PHP](https://www.php.net/)

Para que seja possível a utilização desse loop dentro do seu HTML, é necessário as seguintes linhas:

```
    <?php
        for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
             echo '
                <article class="artigo">
                    <h1>Titulo da noticia</h1>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, bla bla bla, consecetur. Lorem ipsum bla bla.
                    </p>
                </article>
            ';
       }
   ?>
```

Lembre-se de não deixar um espaço após `<?php`, isso pode resultar em problemas futuros. Também é importante ressaltar que se o conteúdo for dinâmico, é de grande importância que você use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHTTPRequest).

Comment: Para completar, explicando que ‘<?=‘ é apenas uma abreviação de ‘<?php echo’. Deixa o código mais limpo.

Comment: @JuniorLike exato.