# CodeIgniter, código com pequeno bug

Tags: php, codeigniter, back-end

Estou acompanhando este tutorial sobre codeigniter:

http://www.dicascodeigniter.com.br/mini-crud-com-codeigniter-3-e-bootstrap/

Ao baixar e rodar o projeto, ele me apresentou os seguintes erros:

- Não reconhece a tag PHP `< ? ... ? >` no começo do `v_home.php`
- Não está listando os itens cadastrados. No banco eles aparecem, mas na listagem/views não.

Apenas baixei, fiz o banco e rodei. Não modifiquei nada.

Como posso resolver isso[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]?

Comment: O código fonte ou parte dele é exibido no lugar dos dados?

Comment: Não entendi, como assim??

Comment: [Código fonte é exibido na tela e não é executado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60366/91)

Comment: Resolvido rray. Muito obrigado!